# Calculating the median amongst groups of rows (SQL)

Tags: sql, median, metabase

I have a relational database with exam results but the query I need only uses one table:

- Results_tbl = student_no INT,
- subject_code VARCHAR(5),
- score FLOAT,
- Date DATE

I need the query to calculate the median number of students who sat exams per subject (factoring that students more than 1 exam per subject) then show which subject has the highest median.

My knowledge of calculating medians on SQL (Metabase) is very limited, I started by using a result_table.student_no count(*) function and GROUP BY results_tbl.subject_code but I do not feel this is the appropriate approach

For each subject code in the table I need

eg.

```
# OF STUDENT WHO SAT EXAM = _ _ _ & MEDIAN # OF STUDENTS = _ _
```

(ORDER BY DESC)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and Metabase is just a front-end for a database, not a database itself) Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your previous question is tagged with SQL Server, I am going to assume that this is what you are using. In which case you can use [`PERCENTILE_CONT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percentile-cont-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) OR [`PERCENTILE_DISC()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percentile-disc-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

e.g.

```
SELECT  t.Col,
        Median_Cont = PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY t.Col) OVER(),
        Median_Disc = PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY t.Col) OVER()
FROM    (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4)) AS t (Col);
```

Gives:

```
Col     Median_Cont     Median_Disc
--------------------------------------
1       2.5             2
2       2.5             2
3       2.5             2
4       2.5             2
```

Or to constrain your results, you would need a subquery:

```
SELECT  t.Col
FROM    (   SELECT  t.Col,
                    Median_Disc = PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5) 
                                    WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY t.Col) OVER()
            FROM    (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4)) AS t (Col)
        ) AS t
WHERE   t.Col = t.Median_Disc;
```

**Result**

```
Col
-----
2
```

For your specific example I think you would also need to include a `PARTITION BY` to ensure the median is caclulated per subject:

```
SELECT  r.subject_code, r.score, r.Date
FROM    (   SELECT  r.*,
                    Median = PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5) 
                                    WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY r.Score) 
                                    OVER(PARTITION BY r.Subject_Code)
            FROM    Results_tbl AS r
        ) AS r
WHERE   r.Score = r.Median;
```